# How to list all users in an administrative group in linux

Tags: linux, unix

i am using  "getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups  > users.txt" but this lists all users and the groups they are in. In my case there are thousands of users I only need the list of users part of a specific group.

current output is in pic I don't need the members of linux_users group

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to grep to narrow down the list that you get. Use some like `grep groupname`.

Grep: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Then you can use awk to only get part of a line.

Awk: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html

So in your case you could do: `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups | grep linux_admins | awk {'print $1'} > users.txt`

Comment: not having much luck with grep it does not show anything just makes a new commandline

Comment: Are you piping into grep? What is the new command you are using now? Should look something like `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups | grep groupname > users.txt`

Comment: I did and says "groups: unix: No such user" seems like its searching for users instead of group names?

Comment: Please post the current output of `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups` Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups | grep linux_admins > users.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Each record in `/etc/group` ends with a list of users that have that group as their supplementary group ( See http://linux.die.net/man/5/group ).
To get all members of your target group, you need to get those plus all users who have the target group as their primary group (in /etc/passwd, identified by your target group's number mentioned in /etc/group).

This script will get you both (you can call it group_ls or something like that):

```
#!/bin/sh
num_membs="$( getent group "$1" |cut -d: -f3,4 )"
num="${num_membs%:*}"; membs="${num_membs#*:}"
( IFS=,
printf '%s\n' $membs
awk -v num=$num -F: ' $4 == num { print $1 } ' /etc/passwd
) | sort -u
```

Alternatively, based on your approach

```
  getent passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs groups |
     grep ":.* $1 .*" |cut -d : -f1
```

should do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the list of users associated with a group (example: `users` below) into an array in bash with the following:

```
IFS=$',\n' read -a names < <(grep '^users:' /etc/group | sed 's/^.*://')
```

Then you can access each user in a simple loop, e.g.

```
for i in ${names[@]}; do echo "$i"; done
```

This will only work for shells that support indexed arrays and process substitution, otherwise the pipe gymnastics are required.